# crash in iOS 10 and iOS 9 with CoreFoundation - common_removeAllObjects

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, ios10, xcode11.3

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000020
common_removeAllObjects

CoreFoundation
common_removeAllObjects + 156

The above given is the stack trace.Not able to find a reference in the code.

I am not able to replicate the issue, it is showing as crashlytics log with crash insight  as:

Heap corruption

> The stack trace indicates that heap corruption may have caused your app to crash. Memory corruption can occur pretty easily from freeing a dangling pointer, a thread race, or bad pointer arithmetic. The important thing to keep in mind is that the resulting crash may happen long after the initial corruption. As a result, the stack trace for this crash might not provide any clues to the location of the bug in your code. However, you can still fix memory issues with tools from Apple. For speedy resolution of memory corruption issues, we recommend regularly auditing your app with Xcode’s memory debugging facilities: Visual Memory Debugger, Zombies Instrument, Address Sanitizer, Thread Sanitizer and malloc diagnostics.

The issue is found in iOS 10 and iOS 9 only. Using Xcode 11.3.1.  Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Can you share more details, like what operation is performed when the code crashes?

Comment: @Manoj  crash is happening when a view controller is presented and then when it is popped to previous, crash happens